# Is there a useful guideline to convert AD&D 1e monsters to the D&D 5e system?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, adnd-1e, conversion

I have a whole continent made up in the 1e (AD&D) system, as well as the 1e books and other 1e monster sources.  A lot of those monsters are not published in 5e, and may never be.  Is there a good set of guidelines for easily converting old monsters from 1e to fit in a shiny new 5e world?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Wizards of the Coast Released a PDF on this topic

In the [October 2015 Rules reference](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-references-october-2015), WoTC released a PDF that was designed to help the conversion of older editions to 5e; both monster statistics and adventures/treasure.

The PDF can be found [here](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DnD_Conversions_1.0.pdf)

The document includes the following quick conversion rules about monster statistics from first and second edition adventures:

> For first and second edition, you can use the
> shorthand monster statistics in the adventure. In these adventures,
> monsters are often more numerous, but they typically deal lower damage
> and have fewer hit points than their fifth edition counterparts. Make
> the following changes to those first- and second-edition monsters:
>
> - Armor Class equals 19 minus the creature’s AC, up to AC 22.
> - Attack roll modifiers are HD/2 + 2, up to +12.
> - Saving throw DCs are 8 + HD/2, up to 20.
> - If a creature has to make a check or saving throw, and should be good at the roll, use the creature’s HD/2 + 2 as a bonus on the roll.
>   Otherwise, use no modifier, or use a penalty to reflect something the
>   creature should be bad at.